# How to update multiselect people picker field in power automate using Update Item action

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate, person-or-group

I have a SharePoint list with Approvers as multiselect mandatory user field. There is a power automate flow which uses SharePoint Update Item action to update few fields.

As the approvers field is a mandatory field I am unable to proceed further to update the records.

Kindly guide me on how to update this multiselect approvers field as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a user field, you have to supply an object with the user claims

```
{
  "claims": "userclaims"
}
```

[image]

In order to do the same for a multiselect field, you have to supply the object in an array

```
[
  {
   "claims": "user1claims"
  },
  {
   "claims": "user2claims"
  }
]
```

[image]
If you are only adding one person, you still have to put the claims object insdie the square brackets

```
[
  {
   "claims": "userclaims"
  }
]
```

[image]

You would then use the output of your compose action in the Update Item action
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please covert this explanations to actions in Power Automate view ? Otherwise I am unable to figure out how I can implement the suggested approach in power automate UI

Comment: @KailashSahoo, updated with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Please following steps:

1. Add a Trigger "When an item is created or modified"

[image]

2. Add an Action "Initialize variable"

[image]

3. Add an Action "Append to an array variable"

[image]

4. Add an Action "Updated item"

[image]